# How to use the immediate constraint with Intel syntax in gcc?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

With inline assembly in GCC, you can specify an immediate asm operand with the `"i"` constraint, like so:

```
void set_to_five(int* p)
{
    asm
    (
        "movl %1, (%0);"
        :: "r" (p)
        ,  "i" (5)
    );
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    set_to_five(&i);
    assert(i == 5);
}
```

Nothing wrong with this so far, except that it's in horrible AT&T syntax. So let's try again with `.intel_syntax noprefix`:

```
void set_to_five(int* p)
{
    asm
    (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
        "mov [%0], %1;"
        ".att_syntax prefix;"
        :: "r" (p)
        ,  "i" (5)
    );
}
```

But this doesn't work, since the compiler inserts a `$` prefix before the immediate value, which the assembler no longer understands.

How do I use the `"i"` constraint with Intel syntax?

Comment: Try using `%c1` (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers).  Also, consider using -masm=intel instead of the the pseudo-ops.

Comment: I must've read that page like 10 times, yet somehow I missed that bit. Thanks! You should post this as answer.

Comment: And as much as I'd like to use `-masm=intel`, it causes trouble when including headers with AT&T syntax asm.

Comment: What headers are you using that have inline asm in them?  Public headers *should* use dialects (see 'Multiple assembler dialects in asm templates' under https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate) for exactly this reason.  But of course not everybody does.

Comment: The djgpp standard library has a few of these... But I'm thinking now I could reimplement them in Intel syntax. Or use macros like `INTEL_ASM_BEGIN`/`INTEL_ASM_END` and define them either to the respective pseudo-ops or nothing depending on the `-masm` setting used. I don't like the multiple dialects feature, code duplication is a bad thing :)

Comment: The problem with this plan is knowing if `-masm` is being used.  I don't believe it sets a define.  As for duplication, well, it depends.  Using dialects can give you something like "int {$}3".  For att it will use the $, but not for intel.  That's a simple example. For more complicated code it can make things hard to read.

Comment: You're right, there's no way to find out which `-masm` syntax the compiler uses. So I took the "easy" way out, got rid of the AT&T syntax headers and changed all my code to `-masm=intel`. I also noticed this makes the `"m"` constraint work as intended.

Comment: I took a quick look at the djgpp headers.  The in/outs and segments would be easy to re-do using dialects.  The farptr stuff seems more problematical.  Some platforms (like Windows) don't let you change fs/gs, since they have an assigned meaning.  However the odds of convincing the djgpp people to update their source are pretty low...

Comment: The only part I really used was the port I/O header. I rewrote it in C++ with Intel asm, [see here](https://gist.github.com/jwt27/1b2d05fe6f8756b4e62249165de5de71). I could add multiple dialects easily, but there's no real need to since don't plan to use `-masm=att` ever again. For far pointers I just add and subtract the segment base adresses to create a near pointer. It works as long as you make sure the DS segment is large enough. (this may become easier in the future with gcc 6, which will add support for FS/GS based variables.)

Comment: Understood.  My point was that if djgpp were prepared to accept a patch, we could fix it for everyone.  And (begin to) establish a principle about how to write inline asm in public headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use %c1 (see [modifiers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers)).

Note that if you are using symbolic names (which I find easier to read/maintain), you can use %c[five].

Lastly, I realize code this is just a "for-instance," but you are modifying memory without telling the compiler.  This is a "bad thing."  Consider either using a output constraint for the memory (`"=m"`) or adding the "memory" clobber.

Comment: This brings up a second question; should I use the `"memory"` clobber for non-memory side effects too (like I/O port access)?

Comment: The point of the memory clobber is to let the compiler know if your asm is going to read memory "other than those listed in the input and output operands."  This lets the compiler know that if it has any values cached in registers, they should be flushed to memory before/reloaded afterwords.  If the I/O operation is indeed "non-memory" (ie isn't writing a block of memory to disk, read a block from disk, etc), then there's (probably) nothing the compiler needs to do.  Hard to say absolutely without specifics.

Comment: I was thinking of hardware I/O ports (`in`/`out` instructions). These things are not kept in C/C++ variables so I don't suppose "memory" will be necessary here, just `asm volatile` to make sure they are executed in the right order.

Comment: If order is a concern, consider adding references to some of the surrounding variables to 'anchor' your asm.  Adding an input or an input+output can help tell gcc where things go.  Note that it is not necessary to actually use all the parameters.